# Ripped off paint on bathtub

Tags: paint, bathtub

The paint on my bathtub has been ripped off so much like this:

[image]

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: The paint was already a fix. You'll need to strip it completely or replace the tub.

Comment: @isherwood Replacing the tub will probably cost too much. If I strip it off, what should do next?

Comment: Maybe just get a big inside-tub bath mat.

Comment: ... or wear a blindfold whenever you're taking a shower.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a cast-iron tub in decent condition below the surface, it can be refinished to look like new. [Here's an article from This Old House](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/article/0,,197046-2,00.html) that explains one process. There are likely vendors who will come to your house to refinish the tub, as well as DIY products. For any repair approach, it's vital to properly prepare the surface by removing the prior paint attempt, patching any deep scratches, and sanding thoroughly to ensure good bonding of the new enamel.

Comment: Most contractors providing tub refinishing prepare the surface themselves as part of the job. In fact, if OP prepares it he will probably be charged the same as if he did not.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, thanks - I didn't mean to suggest the homeowner needs to do the prep, just that proper prep is vital and you can't just paint on a new layer. I've edited the answer so it doesn't suggest anything about whose responsibility the prep is.

Answer (score 0):

Companies do recoat tubs much cheaper than replacement.
The problem is the tub is porcelain, Paint usually won’t last long.
Here is one product that states it works on [porcelain](https://www.miraclemethod.com/bathtub-refinishing.htm).
There are other products this is just 1.